# How to get specific comments when using YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

I want to get all comments including all the replies to comments. I've been using YouTube Data API v3 to get those it's been working fine and good.

But I have 2 questions,

1. In Documentation it is said that using this YouTube Data API v3 to fetch comments list will cost one quota in Google Cloud Console. I wanted to know **what is quota**.
2. How to restrict the number of comments and replies that I get from API to a certain number like 100 or 200 or so.

I've included the code that I've been using.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = 'api_key'


def video_comments(video_id):
    comments = []

    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

    video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part='snippet,replies',
        videoId=video_id
    ).execute()

    while video_response:
        for item in video_response['items']:

            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']

            replycount = 0
            if replycount > 0:
                for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                    reply = reply['snippet']['textDisplay']

                    comments.append(reply)

            comments.append(comment)
        if 'nextPageToken' in video_response:
            video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part='snippet,replies',
                videoId=video_id
            ).execute()
        else:
            break

    print(comments)


video_id = "cOQQEvemIHs"

video_comments(video_id)
```

I've tried to add counter in while loop but it didn't work so I need some effective way to get only a certain number of comments from the API.

Comment: Here is [the quota documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota). Concerning restricting the number of comments, the API proposes a [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#maxResults) parameter, otherwise you have to establish the restriction within your code.

Comment: to establish restriction in the code.  just add a counter and `break` or terminate the `while` loop if this is achieved...